# chrome mobile jquery ajax POST not working

Tags: jquery, ajax, google-chrome, post, mobile

I'm running into a weird bug where a JQuery POST is working in mobile safari, desktop safari, and desktop chrome, but failing on chrome for ios. Here is my ajax request:

```
$.ajax({
  url: '/data',
  cache: false,
  type: 'POST',
  headers: {
    "cache-control": "no-cache"
  },
  data: data,
  success: function() {
    console.log("success");
  },
  error: function() {
    console.log("error");
  }
});
```

I've read about some problems with mobile safari caching post requests, but I don't think that's what's going on here...

Comment: any updates? I just discovered the same bug

Comment: it seems to have only showed up on iphone 4 running ios7.

Comment: thanks. I eventually fixed my own version of this problem by more clearly defining the headers on my django server's response. the issue only ever came up with chrome on ios...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update: The bug is not present on the live site, and is only showing up during testing on localhost. Hopefully this is the case for everyone else, too. At least we can narrow it down a bit.

Answer (score 2):

I gone through same problem in my project ,you should have to mention type of url like .json .xml when you are using chrome for ios.
try it once hope it will work.

Comment: is it still unresolved?any updates..keep demo on plunker or fiddle so that we will able to look into that issue